# Find the missing numbers in the given array

Tags: c++

> Implement a function which takes an array of numbers from 1 to 10 and returns the numbers from 1 to 10 which are missing. examples input: [5,2,6] output: [1,3,4,7,8,9,10]

C++ program for the above approach:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std; 
 
// Function to find the missing elements 

void printMissingElements(int arr[], int N) 
{ 
 

    // Initialize diff 

    int diff = arr[0] - 0; 
 

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
 

        // Check if diff and arr[i]-i 

        // both are equal or not 

        if (arr[i] - i != diff) { 
 

            // Loop for consecutive 

            // missing elements 

            while (diff < arr[i] - i) { 

                cout << i + diff << " "; 

                diff++; 

            } 

        } 

    } 
}
```

Driver Code

```
int main() 
{ 

    // Given array arr[] 

    int arr[] = { 5,2,6 }; 
 

    int N = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); 
 

    // Function Call 

    printMissingElements(arr, N); 

    return 0; 
}
```

How to solve this question for the given input?

Comment: The numbers in your input `arr` are not from 1 to 10, as the requirement states.

Comment: Plzz help me@paolo c++ code... Tell me the right code for the given input

Comment: The input need not be sorted. The simplest solution here would be to create a set of numbers iterating through the input array once and then going from 1 to 10 print all the numbers not in the set. A `bool[10]` array can be used instead of a real set here...

Comment: Also obligatory [no `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), especially not in combination with `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this approach we are using space to reduce execution time. Here the time complexity is O(N) where N is the no of elements given in the array and space complexity is O(1) i.e 10' .

```
 #include<iostream>


void printMissingElements(int arr[], int n){
   
    // Using 1D dp to solve this
   
    int dp[11] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        dp[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
   
    // Traverse through dp list and check for
    // non set indexes
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        if (dp[i] != 1) std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {5,2,6};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    printMissingElements(arr, n);
}
```

Comment: Notice how the example array doesn't respect the problem requirements and is causing UB.

Comment: Again [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/6070341) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6070341)

Comment: 1. Approach is independent of order of inputs so for a given set of inputs in any order will give the same result.  and i have changed the input array as per the question.

Comment: 2. It is basically a header file that includes every standard library. In programming contests, using this file is a good idea, when you want to reduce the time wasted. 

            Only thing to take care is if you try to compile your code with some compiler other than GCC it might fail; e.g. MSVC do not have this header.

          When we import a namespace we are essentially pulling all type definitions into the current scope. The std namespace is huge.
 But for codes with small logical implementation it will be easier to use namespace as std @CostantinoGrana

Answer (score 1):

First of all "plzz" is not an English world. Second, the question is already there, no need to keep writing in comments "if anyone knows try to help me".
Then learn standard headers: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/6070341)
Then learn [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6070341)

Then read the text of the problem: "Implement a function which takes an array of numbers from 1 to 10 and returns the numbers from 1 to 10 which are missing. examples input: [5,2,6] output: [1,3,4,7,8,9,10]"

You need to "**return** the numbers from 1 to 10 which are missing."
I suggest that you really use C++ and get `std::vector` into your toolbox. Then you can leverage algorithms and `std::find` is ready for you.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
 
std::vector<int> missingElements(const std::vector<int> v) 
{ 
    std::vector<int> missing;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), i) == v.end()) {
            missing.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return missing;
}
 
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> arr = { 5, 2, 6 }; 
    std::vector<int> m = missingElements(arr); 
    copy(m.begin(), m.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
 
    return 0; 
}
```

If you want to do something with lower computational complexity you can have an already filled vector and then mark for removal the elements found. Then it's a good chance to learn the [erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
std::vector<int> missingElements(const std::vector<int> v) 
{ 
    std::vector<int> m = { -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    for (const auto& x: v) {
        m[x] = -1;
    }
    m.erase(remove(m.begin(), m.end(), -1), m.end());
    return m;
}
```

Comment: @Saiteja The accepted answer is wrong. It requires more work for fixing.

Comment: Sir, you are right but this solution is also acceptable for arrays where non-repeated elements are present. However, for your given array there is another solution possible. I have just posted it. Kindly, go through it,

Answer (score 0):

```
    void printMissingElements(int arr[], int n,int low, int high)
{
    bool range[high - low + 1] = { false };

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (low <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= high)
            range[arr[i] - low] = true;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= high - low; x++) {
        if (range[x] == false)
           std:: cout << low + x << " ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 5,2,6,6,6,6,8,10 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int low = 1, high = 10;
    printMissingElements(arr, n, low, high);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
vector<int> missingnumbers(vector<int> A, int N)
{ vector<int> v;
  for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    v.push_back(i);
  sort(A.begin(),A.end());
  int j=0;
  while(j<v.size()) {
  if(binary_search(A.begin(),A.end(),v[j]))
    v.erase(v.begin()+j);
    else
    j++;
  }
 return v;
}
```